# AngularJS two way binding for remote data array and local copy

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

In my application i need to get remote orders data, identified by `orderId`.
When i fetch a remote order i have to store in local memory, for further modifications inside the app.
So in my angularjs app i would to create a method (or property) in the controller which, given an `orderId`, returns the local copy of the order, or, if it does not exists, start downloading it from remote server, possibly automatically binding when finished.

Is there a binding pattern which can i use?

I've tried this:

Controller:

```
$scope.ordersDetails = function()
{
    return ordersService.getOrderDetail($scope.orderId);
}
```

Service:

```
   var orderDetails = [];
   var _loadOrderDetail = function (orderId) {
      return $http.get(----).then(function (results) {
        _parseOrder(results.data);
      });
   };
   var _parseOrder = function(orderJson) {
       orderDetails[orderJson.OrderDetail.ID] = .......
   }
    var _getOrderDetail = function (orderId)
    {
        if (!orderDetails[orderId])
        {
            orderDetails[orderId] = [];
            // start downloading from remote server
            _loadOrderDetail(orderId);
            return;
        }
        return orderDetails[orderId];

    }
    ordersServiceFactory.getOrderDetail = _getOrderDetail;
```

HTML:

```
<!--
ordersDetails().orderDetails is a json object
ordersDetails().orderItems is an array of json objects.
-->

<div>{{ordersDetails().orderDetails.Customer}}</div>
<div class="item" ng-repeat="orderItem in ordersDetails().orderItems">
  {{orderItem.ID}}
</div>
```

But i don't know if it is a good pattern; moreover the ng-repeat directive is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: where is the call to `$http`?  Angular HTTP calls work with promises (`$q`).  You should read up on how this mechanism is meant to work.

Comment: Yes, so you need to `return` the call to `_loadOrderDetail(orderId);` and then use a `then` to handle the promise in the controller: `ordersService.getOrderDetail($scope.orderId).then(function(response){ //something }):`